# Forcing the browser to ignore cached iframe contents in WordPress without using a plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, caching, iframe

I have the situation where I need to update a static HTML file on a server running WordPress daily. This is referenced by an iframe on a single page.

I would like to prevent the iframe source from being cached, but I can't install a plugin or update WordPress themes.

I had the idea of using a script to set the source to use a query with a random parameter, but I don't believe WordPress allows JavaScript.

I also tried adding the following to the header on the iframe to no avail:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to save the file as a .PHP instead of .HTML